# How to tell from a media file if it's a video or an audio?

Tags: amazon-s3, audio, video, ffmpeg, aws-media-convert

I have some files - audio and video files - stored in an aws s3 bucket, which can have different containers and stuff, and I would like to send them to the aws mediaConvert(MC). My issue is that I need to know whenever the file is an audio or a video file, because I need to configure the MC accordingly. The main app on the server is php based, but this information might not be that interesting.

I have ffmpeg, and I already use ffprobe to get the file duration, however I can't tell from the returning data if it's a video or audio-only file. And [in an another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444571/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-video-file-is-audio-only) someone said that maybe I can get this info by using the ffmpeg, but as far as I know that requires me to download the file from the s3 to the server.
There is also an s3 function that I can use to get the header of a specific object, which contains the mime type of the file, however this sometimes returns as audio/mpeg for video files, which then configures the MC incorrectly.

I could also check the error message from the first job create of MC, which then tells me about the issue, and I can resend the file with the correct configuration, but then the job is marked as failed with error, which doesn't feel right to do.

So my question is; **what would be the best approach to tell from a media file if it's a video or audio only?** It's possible that ffmpeg or ffprobe can do it remotely, but I just don't know the tools deeply enough, so I'm not entirely sure that it can only work in that way I described it.

Comment: See duplicate link [Using ffprobe to check if file is audio or video only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32289198/). No need for `jq` or other additional parsing tools as shown in the answer below because you can get `ffprobe` to output only the info you need.

Comment: yep, it seems like a duplicate. I would like to point out however, that I couldn't find the question with the information I had above here when I posted the question, and I spent a few times searching for it. And while I didn't knew that ffprobe is capable of doing that, I knew that I would like to do it without downloading the file to the server, if possible.
Also at the end I never tried jq, just got the info from the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams sample.mp4
```

The above command outputs input file's (here: `sample.mp4`) parameters along with audio and video streams' details. You can see the sample output [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/fcd42d7b).

What you're interested in is `.streams[].codec_type` to figure out if the input file contains only audio, only video or both streams. You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for that matter, for example:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams sample.mp4 | jq .streams[].codec_type
"video"
"audio"
```

or parse the output JSON in any other way.

Comment: I see, I think this is what I need, but I'll check it out first and then I'll come back to u